# mysql timediff no proper output when endtime is 24hrs

Tags: mysql, date, date-difference

I'm using datatype time to calculate the class taken timings. For calculation I use `TIMEDIFF(endtime,starttime)`.

#### Query

```sql
SELECT TIMEDIFF('00:26:08','21:58:18') FROM students_session WHERE id='#'
```

I'm not getting the proper o/p which is `02:27:50`. Instead I get `-21:32:10`, which is wrong.

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that **you** know that `'00:26:08'` is after `'21:58:18'` (following morning), but MySQL is not aware, thus the result is correct from MySQL point of view.

You either need to provide a date part, where the `end_date` falls to the next day, or you need to add 24 hours (1 day) to the `end_date`. These will tell MySQL that the `end_date` is greater than the `start_date` and you will get the results you expect.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(timeadd('00:26:08','24:00:00'),'21:58:18') from students_session where id='#'
```