# MySQL TIMEDIFF between two TIME only (not DATETIME)

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.6

I have a table `shift` with columns `start_time` (TIME) and `end_time` (TIME):

```
+------------+----------+
| start_time | end_time |
+------------+----------+
| 07:00:00   | 16:00:00 |
| 15:00:00   | 23:00:00 |
| 22:00:00   | 07:00:00 |
| 12:00:00   | 21:00:00 |
| 12:00:00   | 09:00:00 |
| 10:00:00   | 20:00:00 |
| 23:00:00   | 01:00:00 |
| 21:00:00   | 05:00:00 |
+------------+----------+
```

I want to find all the shifts that will be ending in next 15 minutes. Above is the sample data, it can have minutes as well btw.

This is what I have tried:

`SELECT start_time, end_time 
FROM shift 
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, TIME(NOW()))) < 900;`

Result:

```
+------------+----------+
| start_time | end_time |
+------------+----------+
| 22:00:00   | 07:00:00 |
| 12:00:00   | 09:00:00 |
| 23:00:00   | 01:00:00 |
| 21:00:00   | 05:00:00 |
+------------+----------+
```

This query should work when I don't have any night shifts in my table (i.e when `start_time` is greater than `end_time`). Can anyone help me solve the case for night shifts.

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. This is going to be too tricky to bother with.

Comment: @Strawberry please feel free to assume a column with `id` as primary key, as I have it in my real application. let me know if I should add it here for clarity.

Comment: Of course you should!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql timediff no proper output when endtime is 24hrs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340704/mysql-timediff-no-proper-output-when-endtime-is-24hrs)

Comment: @Strawberry added a duplicate reference where I answered exactly the same question

Comment: @Shadow I voted 'unclear' already :-(

Comment: @Shadow thanks, I am trying your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that MySQL assumed both TIMEs to be on the same day. So you will get negative results when `end_time` is in the past, which will trigger your `< 900` condition, giving you too many results.

I see two ways to fix this:

1: Extend the condition to remove negative results

```
SELECT start_time, end_time
FROM foo
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, TIME(NOW()))) > 0
AND   TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, TIME(NOW()))) < 900
```

2: The shorter way, add 24 hours to all negative values. Usually the MOD() function would do the trick, but somehow it doesn't do this in MySQL, so you also need to add 24 hours to your values:

```
SELECT start_time, end_time
FROM foo
WHERE MOD(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, TIME(NOW()))) + 24*60*60, 24*60*60) < 900
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query..

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM shift
      `WHERE end_time > CAST(now() - interval 15 minute AS time)
       and end_time < `CAST(now() as time);
```

Answer (score -1):

Once try this way

```
select * from aa_shift where

TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start_time,end_time) < 15

or

TIMEDIFF(start_time,end_time) < 15
```

Comment: [TIMEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) accepts only two parameters.

Comment: hmm TimeDiff will not work.. may be u should use timestampdiff and check if end_time > start time i think u need to write some cursor